# Difference between PhantomJSDriver and FirefoxDriver

Tags: java, selenium, phantomjs

I'm trying to write integration tests that require doing GET requests in HTTPS and the tests will run in a remote server. Which driver would be better and how could I set this up? When I do a `driver.get` it gets stuck there forever.

```
capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
capabilities.setCapability("takeScreenshot", true);
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
capabilities.setCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Unknown; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.34 (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/534.34");
driver = new PhantomJSDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: What do you mean `driver.get`?

Comment: I just mean `driver.get("https://www.example.com")`

Comment: Oh ok. Have you tried without `DesiredCapabilities`? Just try `new PhantomJSDriver();` Then, try adding capabilities one by one until you eventually find the one being the cause of the problem.

Comment: By the way, the title of your question doesn't reflect your actual problem and vice versa. Both questions are interesting though.